# Phonegap - How do i make the statusbar black?

Tags: iphone, cordova

Pretty simple one that I just seemingly can't find the answer to.

How can i change the iPhone statusbar (thin bar right at the top with the reception/batter etc) from default grey to black in my **PhoneGap** iPhone application?

Thanks,
Glen

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A PhoneGap-iPhone application is just a regular Xcode iPhone project.

Add `UIStatusBarStyle`:`UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque` to your `Info.plist`.

1. Open your Xcode project (e.g. `MyApp.xcodeproj`)
2. Open your `Info.plist` file (e.g. `MyApp-Info.plist`)
3. Add a new row:

   - Key: `Status bar style`
   - Value: `Opaque black style`

If you are viewing the RAW Key/Value pairs, then use:

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>  
<string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string>
```

You can right-click in MyApp-Info.plist to toggle the RAW Key/Value pairs.

Answer (score 3):

just set

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

Comment: Thanks! where abouts do i set that option?

Comment: you can put it in - (void)viewDidLoad  method

Comment: Thanks for that!  Managed to figure it out, but yeah, the plist option ended up being the easiest way... it wrote itself

Answer (score 0):

When a PhoneGap Project is created, there is an `<ApplicationName>AppDelegate.m` file created in the project.

Inside of the `(void)viewDidLoad` method, you can make modifications to the view however you choose.