# How to make PhoneGap status bar in iOS translucent?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm using PhoneGap to build an iOS app and can't seem to get that full-screen/translucent status bar effect to work.

I set the *-info.plist's `Status bar style` to `Transparent black style (alpha of 0.5)`, which works while the splash screen is up.  But the status bar turns black when PhoneGap's UIWebView is displayed.

I tried setting the `apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style` meta tag to `black-translucent` in my index.html, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

I tried setting phonegap.plist's `TopStatusBar` option to `blackTranslucent`, but that didn't have any effect either.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Actually the Status Bar is translucent.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView 
{
    // only valid if StatusBarTtranslucent.plist specifies a protocol to handle
    if(self.invokeString)
    {
        // this is passed before the deviceready event is fired, so you can access it in js when you receive deviceready
        NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"var invokeString = \"%@\";", self.invokeString];
        [theWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
    }

    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

    CGRect frame = theWebView.frame;
    NSLog(@"The WebView: %f %f %f %f", frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
    frame = theWebView.superview.frame;
    NSLog(@"The WebView superview: %f %f %f %f", frame.origin.x, frame.origin.y, frame.size.width, frame.size.height);

    frame.size.height += frame.origin.y;
    frame.origin.y = 0;

    [theWebView.superview setFrame:frame];

    return [ super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView ];
}
```

The log result of this code shows:

```
The WebView: 0.000000 0.000000 320.000000 460.000000
The WebView superview: 0.000000 20.000000 320.000000 460.000000
```

so fixing the webview.superview frame you can get the effect of UIStatusBarTranslucent

```
CGRect frame = theWebView.superview.frame;

frame.size.height += frame.origin.y;
frame.origin.y = 0;

[theWebView.superview setFrame:frame];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add in your Info.plist for your app:

```
Key: Status bar style
Value:  Black translucent style
```

or if you are using raw key value pairs

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>  
<string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent</string>
```

This answer is adapted from another given by mwbrooks for a similar question.  Give it a try.

( [Phonegap - How do i make the statusbar black?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049088/phonegap-how-do-i-make-the-statusbar-black) )

Or maybe, in your (void)viewDidLoad method of your **AppDelegate.m, you can put:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response maujee. The good 'ol *.plist solution seems to only work on the rendered app for the default or black setting, unfortunately not for translucent. I tried the code in all `AppDelegate.m` functions but it seems like it's being overridden,  flicking back to black.