# Phonegap 3.8.0 & iOS8 statusbar

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Pretty simple question really. I want to be able to change the font color of the statusbar in my Phonegap app. Note: I am not using Phonegap Build, just building the app in phpStorm and using Phonegap serve to show it in my iPhone app.

I have searched Google and Stackoverflow for possible solutions and they all don't work.

Tried solutions:

- Meta tag index.html
- Editing MyApp-Info.plist ([Phonegap - How do i make the statusbar black?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4049088/phonegap-how-do-i-make-the-statusbar-black))
- Using several Phonegap/Cordova plugins and editing the config.xml. This gave me various 'cannot be parsed' errors when launching `phonegap serve`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have tried the **status bar plugin**? It's should work.

Just install the statusbar plugin by terminal:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.statusbar
```

Then set your style preferences for the status bar, using your config.xml:

```
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
```

---

I think that you can only set custom background color for the status bar in iOS, or just set white/black color for font but nothing else.

I repeat, not 100% sure but I think you can't set custom font color for status bar in iOS.

Comment: Thanks @massimo-polimeni but unfortunately my terminal gives the error: 'command not recognised' when using 'cordova'. Any solutions for that so I can try your idea?

Comment: it means that you have not cordova installed. Type in your terminal "sudo npm install -g cordova" and try again :)

Comment: Alrighty, seems logical enough ;-). My professor (yes, this is for university) said I can just replace your command with 'phonegap'. This seemed to work. Just curious: Is this 'acceptable' in the industry or considered an hybrid solution?

Comment: Cordova or phonegap are hybrid solution, but don't worry they are widely used in the workplace to reduce costs and development time for "simple" solutions